# Broadcast Service ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED delay android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-handler, android-timer

could you please explain me why i can't start my activity from broadcast reciever with 5 sec. delay in this way.

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                context.startActivity(i);


            },5000);



  Handler handler = new Handler();
   hanlder.postDelay(new Runnable(){
       @Override
            public void run() {
                context.startActivity(i);


            },5000);
         }
```

And if you have any suggestions how to delay activity, I'll be very grateful for advice.

Comment: If this is truly from an `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver, you cannot reliably do anything in the background from a manifest-registered receiver, as your process may be terminated at any point after `onReceive()` returns. If you want to show UI when the phone boots, build a home screen.

Comment: I want to prevent closing my application by another custom or system app at the boot time

Comment: Fortunately, that is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: why?I guess i don't do nothing crimminal
This is my AndroidMinifest.xml :https://pastebin.com/2ThuYgMt

Comment: This my BroadcastReciever: https://pastebin.com/v4WZnRAV